# C#/MySQL - get a date from database

Tags: c#, mysql, date

in my database I have a row from type date. I want to to display those dates in my C# program, but I have problems at writing the query. At the moment I try it using:

```
public string getAge(string Name) 
    {
        connection con = new connection(); //The object for the class with the connection string 
        con.conopen(); //opens the connection
        string Age = "";
        MySqlCommand cmd_getAge = new MySqlCommand("Select 'Age' from profile where Name = '" + Name + "';", con.con); 
        MySqlDataReader Reader = cmd_getAge.ExecuteReader();
        if (Reader.HasRows)
        {
            try
            {
                while (Reader.Read())
                {
                    Age = Reader.GetString(0);
                }
            }
            finally
            {
                Reader.Close();
                con.conclose();
            }
        }
        return Age;
    }
```

VS returns me as result just "Age" and also no error.

If it is relevant, I am using Visual Studio Ultimate 2013 on Windows 7.

Comment: Maybe that's because you're just selecting age as the query says. Have you tried selecting the date as well?? What does your table look like? Also, you need to read up on parameterizing your queries -- you are vulnerable to SQL injection.

Comment: What is the type of the field in your database? ("Age" is a bad field anyway - it should be DateOfBirth or something like that. Someone's age keeps changing; their date of birth doesn't.)

Comment: Additionally, you should use parameterized SQL rather than constructing the SQL dynamically. Don't put it off - fix that *now* to avoid SQL injection attacks.

Comment: Check out the Entity Framework

Answer (score 1):

The issue is that you are selecting the specific value 'Age'. If you remove the quotes around Age, the column's values will be selected instead.

```
public string getAge(string Name) 
    {
        connection con = new connection(); //The object for the class with the connection string 
        con.conopen(); //opens the connection
        string Age = "";
        MySqlCommand cmd_getAge = new MySqlCommand("Select Age from profile where Name = '" + Name + "';", con.con); 
        MySqlDataReader Reader = cmd_getAge.ExecuteReader();
        if (Reader.HasRows)
        {
            try
            {
                while (Reader.Read())
                {
                    Age = Reader.GetString(0);
                }
            }
            finally
            {
                Reader.Close();
                con.conclose();
            }
        }
        return Age;
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Explanation in the comments:

```
//why on earth would you ever return an Age as a string!?
public int getAge(string Name) 
{
    //Notice the placeholder in the string. This is important.
    string sql = "Select Age from profile where Name = @Name ;";

    //I see you have your own connection class. However, you used it wrong.
    //If you can't wrap your connection in a using block or try/finally block
    // you're potentially leaving connections hanging open.
    // Do that enough, and you'll lock yourself out of your database.
    //Better just to provide the connection string as a property
    using (var cn = new MySqlConnection("connection string here"))
    using (var cmd = new MySqlCommand(sql, cn))
    { 
        //use the actual db type and length here
        // this parameter makes your code safe from sql injection attacks
        // without the parameter, you're practically begging to get hacked.
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@Name", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 50).Value = Name;  

        cn.Open();          
        using (var reader = cmd.ExecuteReader())
        {
            //no need to ever check HasRows. 
            //If HasRows would return false, so will reader.Read(), and everything still works the same
            if (reader.Read())
            {
                //surely you're not storing this information in the database as a string!?
                // that would be awful.
                // Age should be an integer.
                // More than that, you should be storing a date, and then calculate the age on retrieval
                DateTime origin = Reader.GetDateTime(0);
                int Age = DateTime.Today.Year - origin.Year;
                if (origin > today.AddYears(-Age)) Age--;
                return Age;
            }
        }
    }
    return 0; //or throw an exception here
}
```

And because the comments make this kind of lengthy, here's the concise version:

```
public int getAge(string Name) 
{
    string sql = "Select Age from profile where Name = @Name ;";

    using (var cn = new MySqlConnection("connection string here"))
    using (var cmd = new MySqlCommand(sql, cn))
    { 
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@Name", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 50).Value = Name;  

        cn.Open();          
        using (var reader = cmd.ExecuteReader())
        {
            if (reader.Read())
            {
                DateTime origin = Reader.GetDateTime(0);
                //calculate the age
                int Age = DateTime.Today.Year - origin.Year;
                if (origin > today.AddYears(-Age)) Age--;
                return Age;
            }
        }
    }
    return 0; //or throw an exception here
}
```

Answer (score 1):

thank you all for your help! It works now :D Andrew Walters and Joel Coehoorn are both right. For those with the same problem, I post the finished method. It is just the code from Joel Coehoorn with some fixes.

```
public int getAge_Test(string Name)
{
string sql = "Select Age from profile where Name = @Name ;";
  using (var con = new MySqlConnection("server=127.0.0.1;user id=root;persistsecurityinfo=True;database=social_media"))
        using (var cmd = new MySqlCommand(sql, con))
        {
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@Name", MySqlDbType.VarChar, 50).Value = Name; //MySQL has no defintion for SqldbType and also Nvarchar

            con.Open();
            using (var reader = cmd.ExecuteReader())
            {
                if (reader.Read())
                {
                    DateTime origin = reader.GetDateTime(0);
                    //calculate the age
                    int Age = DateTime.Today.Year - origin.Year;
                    if (origin > DateTime.Today.AddYears(-Age)) Age--; //Visual Studio also does not know "today", just "DateTime.Today"
                    return Age;
                }
            }
        }
        return 0; //or throw an exception here
    }
```